# How can we build string for multi parameters?

Tags: java, android

I would like implement code some thing like here.

```
String text = "world, java";
String.format("Hello %s cool %s", text);
//result: Hello world cool java
```

Answer (score 1):

By:

- first turning that **one** string with your parameters into an array of strings
- and then passing that array to the format call

You see, that method

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args) {
```

As that one takes zero to many arguments!

In other words: you can use `split()` to dissect your one string into an array, and then pass that. Or, you just pass the different parameters manually:

```
String.format("Hello %s cool %s", parm1, parm2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "world";
String otherText = "java";
String result = String.format("Hello %s cool %s", text, otherText);
//result: Hello world cool java
```